# Remove argsort function in "classify" for images?

Tags: python, numpy, np.argsort

I'm trying to remove the argsort function, so that it will just print in order of prediction classes (I.e. if I am trying to predict "a-d" classifications, it will always just print in "a-d" rather than highest to lowest score). Any advice?

This is from: https://github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_image_classifier/blob/master/src/label_image.py

'''with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction i.e. the most likely result
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

```
predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
         {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

# Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

for node_id in top_k:
    human_string = label_lines[node_id]
    score = predictions[0][node_id]
    print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))'''
```

Comment: That's perfect, I did have to do np.sort(top_k). Basically needed the output to be "a: prediction score, b: prediction score," and so on no matter what category had the highest prediction. Thanks!

Comment: I've moved my comment to an answer. Please consider thumbs up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to go through the same `top_k` values but in their original order, not sorted according to `predictions`? Then do `for node_id in sort(top_k):`.